# Is it possible to create an OData service on Google App Engine using Java or Python

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to find a way to expose data from BigQuery to reporting tools but it seems that most tools do not support connecting to BigQuery directly. I have been looking at exposing Tables and Views created on BigQuery via OData. I cannot seem to find anything that confirms that it is possible to create an OData feed from BigQuery via Google App Engine.

All I can find on the web is information that Apache Olingo does not work with properly with Google App Engine and that there are no Python OData modules. Does anyone know if it is possible to create an OData feed via Java or Python on Google App Engine?

Comment: Possibly this? https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/

Comment: Thank you. I saw that prior to posting here. Odata4j seems to not be maintained anymore for the last 2 years and there are posts stating it causes issues with GAE.

Comment: Did you find a reslution to this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up abandoning the idea.